# Jberet - Retryable exception class working?

Tags: jberet

Is there a way to see in the log that the retry is happening? I need to know if this is working in our test environment before implementing it into production.

There are rare instances when we get the following due to a portion of the key being a timestamp and data coming in to the table from various sources. We need to have the writer retry when we get a - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505

```
    <chunk>
        ...
        <retryable-exception-classes>
            <include class="com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException"></include>
        </retryable-exception-classes>
    </chunk>
```

Answer (score 0):

JBeret does not log these event, but you can implement some [listeners defined by batch spec](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/batch/api/chunk/listener/package-frame.html) to act on you own. For example, `RetryReadListener`, `RetryWriteListener`, or `RetryProcessListener`.